# Display value from async pipe next to corresponding input in FormArray

Tags: angular, rxjs, formarray, async-pipe

I need to display an employee name next to the corresponding employee number for "x" number of employees.

A parent form will provide the total number of employees required.

As each employee number is entered an http get will obtain the corresponding employee name.
Then if another employee is required an input for the next employee number will be displayed.

This is an Angular Reactive Form and each employee id/name combination is part of a FormArray.

An async pipe is used to pull in the employee name.
When 1 is entered as the id for the first employee the correct name appears.
The problem is that when 2 is entered as the id for the next employee both names change to the new name.

Have not been able to resolve by parsing the FormArray.  If that isn't possible would it be better to combine the returned observables somehow and parse the names into the correct fields?

Here's a stackblitz that shows the problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dr9jjy

Comment: Within your employee component, you're rendering different FormControls and all of them are subscribing to the same Observable. Whenever the Observable emits a new value all subscriber will update.

Comment: Why don't you just create a select field within each FormControl, instead of have to type in id's?

Comment: The users will be scanning in the id's with a barcode scanner.  But I could switch to a select...

Comment: Understood. Still I would populate the employee name through a select box and if needed, disable it. Next to it you can keep your input field, and bind it to the same FormControl. So your select field will change whenever you change the id en vice-versa. And as you would like to scan, another option would also not to render you form dynamically through the parent form, but just listen to new scan events, and then add a new formcontrol with the employee id already included from the scan.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if this is off topic...  By "listen to new scan events" do you mean event binding or "subscribing"?

Comment: It depends on what type of scanning you prefer. Hardware vs. Software scanning. Your current setup requires the user to select the input field, then scan the barcode through a hardware scanner. This is similar to a keyboard input, therefore you can add an `keydown` eventlistener to the document body at ngOnInit (and remove the listener at ngOnDestroy) and work with this input data. The second option is to work through the camera of your device. You should check `@zxing/ngx-scanner` https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner This will detect barcode from your camera and convert it to text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observable `employeeName$` is contains only one name.
The observable `employeeName$` is duplicated as the number of the `ngFor` number of loop.

Comment: Consider this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2nusza?file=src/app/employee.component.ts

Comment: This is great!  Thank you!  I had tried to call a function earlier but had it completely wrong being a newb.